# Is there any app like webrunner (firefox addon)?

Tags: firefox, prism, add-on

I would like to know whether there is any app similar to webrunner(formerly prism). this firefox addon allows web applications to be launched from the desktop and configured independently of the default web browser , somewhat similar to chrome's application shortcut.

In chrome it will not allow to have multiple tabs inside the same instance but webrunner can. That's the main reason why I stick with webrunner . Now the problem is that the creators of webrunner discontinued its development, So it will not support on latest versions of firefox. Please suggest me some app similar to webrunner .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome + Profile Manager extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pobhfaiabikkbaheoohmojdkkdmladgo#detail/pobhfaiabikkbaheoohmojdkkdmladgo) provides an OK substitute.

Comment: Thank you very much tom. I think this will serve my purpose.